# excluding certain subfolders in vbs

Tags: vbscript, directory

I'm trying to exlcude certain subfolders when enumerating a folder list with vbs
so far I have:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    wscript.echo objSubfolder.Name  
Next
```

which returns:

All Users
Default
Default User
james
michael
Public
simon

I would like create an exlcusion list for the generic folders, All Users, Default etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know which ones to exclude and then use a conditional statement.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    If objSubfolder.Name <> "All Users" And objSubfolder.Name <> "Default" _
            And objSubfolder.Name <> "Default User" And objSubfolder.Name <> "Public" Then
        WScript.echo objSubfolder.Name
    End If
Next
```